# Issue installing Fastlane on Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fastlane

I'm trying to install fastlane on an EC2 instance and have run into some problems. First, if I try to install fastlane right out of the gate (sudo gem install fastlane -NV) I get an error saying one of the prerequisites requires Ruby 2.1 or greater. So I installed Ruby 2.4 `sudo yum install ruby24` and made sure to change the default ruby version (2.0 -> 2.4). I tried installing fastlane again and got this error:

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h
ERROR: Error installing fastlane:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

It looks like this is a fairly common issue that is usually resolved by doing something like `yum install ruby-devel` but this doesn't fix it for me. My ruby-devel version is 2.0-0.3 which makes me think this is out of sync with my new Ruby version (although when I try to install ruby-devel it says it is up to date with the latest version). Also, /user/share/ruby/include doesn't exist and neither does the ruby.h file. I've tried a few different ways to get around this but all have been unsuccessful. If someone has an idea what I can do to get over this I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you got any solution?